# How to write a tekton result api example call

Tags: tekton

I'd like to query the results of taskruns from tektoncd result api, but I have a hard time putting the query together. Can you help me, please?

I've completed the steps at https://github.com/tektoncd/results/blob/main/docs/install.md

Not sure how a curl call would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example API call querying for Tekton-related objects:

```
curl -k --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxx' \
  https://api-k8s.xxx.com:6443/apis/tekton.dev/v1beta1/namespaces/YOUR_NAMESPACE_HERE/pipelineruns | jq '.[]'
curl -k --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxx' \
  https://api-k8s.xxx.com:6443/apis/tekton.dev/v1beta1/namespaces/YOUR_NAMESPACE_HERE/taskruns/YOUR_RESOURCE_NAME_HERE | jq '.[]'
```

[See Kubernetes docs, for guidance building URLs when querying the API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#resource-uris)

Knowing of a taskrun name, we can query for its results with the following:

```
curl -s -k --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxx' \
   https://api-k8s.xxx.com:6443/apis/tekton.dev/v1beta1/namespaces/ci/taskruns/scalelite-recording-importer-1.3.4-1-build \
   | jq .status.taskResults
[
  {
    "name": "IMAGE_DIGEST",
    "type": "string",
    "value": "sha256:14e52d648f6e99e4b339272658b2a7d57f81f145b0f3f178a0deccb65300a75c"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

tekton api-server used grpc, curl command maybe not be applicable for grpc, you can use grpcurl